# Extracting data along way using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis

I have a task to get the parcel numbers along a specific way.
The way is a vector layer with specific points, and the parcel numbers are supported via WMS server.
The task is splitted in to two tasks:
First is to write down all the parcels that are crossed by the way,
second for given parcel write out all of points.

> EXAMPLE:
>
> First task: way goes
>
> 135/3; 135/5; 503; 333/7; 333/6; 332/2; 499; 613; 498; 303; 302/2
>
> Second task: parcels containing points
>
> 135/3 - 19/L-975; 333/7 - 20/L-975; 333/6 - 21/L-975; 332/2 - 22/L-975; 613 -  23/L-975 & 24/L-975

The manual writting down all of the parcels takes much time. And for a large regions is problematic.
Is it possible to create some kind of rule or script to extract this data automatically?

[image]

Comment: Can you get the parcel information in vector format or do you have to use the WMS?

Comment: Well I have to use the WMS because the information can change, and also  the vide area of ground to cover.

Answer (score 1):

To evaluate if parcels intersect the way vector line you will need the parcel data in either vector format (e.g. shapefile, some-sort of spatial database/table, or WFS).  Once you have all the layers in vector format you may use pyqgis .geometry().intersects() method to find parcels that intersect the way layer and also those parcels that have a point feature in them too.

Here is a general code example of this:

```
for feature1 in layerr1.getFeatures():
  for feature2 in layerr2.getFeatures():
    if feature1.geometry().intersects(feature2.geometry()):
      # continue on with logic
```

Comment: there are also GUI tools to select the intersects

Comment: Can you pleas tell me the names of these GUI tools? Im a beginer in QGIS and I dont know much for coding in it.